# Sitecore Error: AddFromTemplate - Add access required

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to add an image item to the content tree - but I get an access denied error at the following point:

item.Add("New Node1"...

The complete code of my method is:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Database master;
master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Item item = master.Items["/sitecore/Content/Media/Images/Places"];
//  item.Fields["Related Issues"].Value = "Asia and the Pacific";
if (item != null)
{
    // add a new Item based on  the Document Template
    Item itm = item.Add("New Node1", master.Templates[new ID(new Guid("EJ0F53DF-5486-4UF4-A2D1-64C119E419A5"))]);
    if (itm != null)
    {
        // report the Item path to the User
        Response.Write(itm.Paths.Path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure that the context user has the item:create access right to the parent item. You may need to use a security user switcher or security disabler.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible that the context of the user Sitecore is running in does not have permissions to this part of the content tree. Check this using the Access Viewer tool. If this is the case then wrap the method in the Security Disabler, like so:

```cs
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
  // enter your code here
}
```